# Check if multivariate confidence elipsoid is within another multivariate confidence elipsoid in

Tags: confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis

If I computed two multivariate confidence regions for two independent samples. How can I check if the confidence region of one sample is completely within the confidence region of the other sample ? I do assume normal distributed data which would resemble (if I am correct) to a hyperelipse.